# Difference between collective and non-collective mpi communications

Tags: c++, concurrency, parallel-processing, mpi

What is the difference between collective and non-collective communications in MPI?
I've tried to understand difference between `MPI_File_read` and `MPI_File_read_all` but failed. Both of these functions use the communicator that was passed to the `MPI_File_open` function as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collective calls require all rank processes in the communicator to make a matching call "together", allowing the implementation to explicitly cooperate between processes. The definition of what constitutes a "matching" call varies with the function call semantics.

In non-collective calls each process operates independently, and there is no requirement that all the ranks in a communicator participate in the call.

From MPI Spec 2.4:

> collective
> A procedure is collective if all processes in a process group need to invoke the procedure. A collective call may or may not be synchronizing. Collective calls over the same communicator must be executed in the same order by all members of the process group.

Comment: If you're only familiar with `MPI_All` routines such as `Allreduce` you may think that they deliver the same result on every process. `MPI_File_read_all` is different in that process can have a different file pointer, so the data read can be different individually. Thought I'd point it out.